# How to add image cache headers?

Tags: 8, caching, .htaccess, media

When doing SEO tests, we consistently seeing a message for cache headers on images. We were thinking of implementing but cannot find the appropriate way to test this as the x-cache still gives a MISS.

Below is the htaccess file we have to accommodate for adding cache header for images.

How can I test to see the performance gain if I did this?

```
# One month
<filesMatch ".(css|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|ico)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2628000, public"
</filesMatch>
```

Comment: x-cache is really only useful for pages that hit PHP. What does https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/ say under Leverage browser caching for images?

Comment: @mikeytown2 under "Leverage browser caching for the following cacheable resources" it only mentions JS and CSS files, not images. I could not find a section that specifically says for images.

Comment: Then the cache header is working for images. x-cache does not measure the browser cache, only CDN or server level caches https://docs.fastly.com/guides/performance-tuning/understanding-cache-hit-and-miss-headers-with-shielded-services

Answer (score 1):

Currenty working on that. The code

```
# One month
 <filesMatch ".(css|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|ico)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2628000, public"
 </filesMatch>
```

helped me to remove images from the list below [https://developers.google.com/speed/](https://developers.google.com/speed)

[image]